# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null just in online website

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a website without any errors when it's offline. but in online when I want to save a form, It takes time and nothing happens. And I see this error in console:::

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

I have read all of the related topics and every thing is right about my website. Do you have a new idea?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!. The error message is likely to contain a line number in your js file. Can you share the block of code that contains that line?

Comment: Hi, yes try to provide a [mcve]